# Не могу разобрться с кроном

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, cron

Есть два файла. Первый -- python код (say_hello.py):

```
def write_text(text):
    with open('text.txt', 'a') as the_file:
        the_file.write(text + '\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    write_text('bla-bla')
```

Второй -- shell script который этот файл запускает (hello.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 /home/ubuntu/say_hello.py
```

И есть cron, который запускает sh файл каждую минуту ($ sudo crontab -e):

```
* * * * * /home/ubuntu/hello.sh
```

Почему ничего не работает?)

Comment: Вот если бы у вас в системе был настроен почтовый сервер, например, exim или postfix, то cron при появлении ошибки прислал бы пользователю ( от имени которого запускается скрипт) письмо, в котором можно было бы узнать подробности. А так вангую, что нет прав на создание файла или на запись в него.

Comment: Дело не в правах т.к. он даже обычный print("Hello") не хочет выполнять.

Comment: А где вы ожидаете увидеть результат выполнения print(“hello”)?

Comment: ну только в терминале, больше ему появится негде.

Comment: А не будет ничего. Можете попробовать более простой вариант в кронтабе: * * * * * echo “hello”. При наличие в системе MTA придет письмо со словом hello. Или в вашем случае - тишина.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### шаги диагностики

1. определите, запущена ли вообще программа *cron* (приведён пример вывода):

   ```
   $ pgrep -ax cron
   379 /usr/sbin/cron -f
   ```
2. определите, разрешено ли пользователю, от имени которого вы собираетесь выполнять задания, этим заниматься (у пользователя `root` обычно нет никаких ограничений).

   если имеется файл `/etc/cron.allow`, то пользователь должен быть в нём упомянут. если этого файла нет, но есть `/etc/cron.deny`, то пользователь *не должен* быть в нём упомянут.

   если нет обоих файлов, то обычно всем пользователям разрешено создавать задания (с помощью программы *crontab*).
3. выполнив от нужного пользователя

   ```
   $ crontab -e
   ```

   создайте минимальное проверочное задание. например:

   ```
   date >> /tmp/какой-нибудь-файл
   ```

   укажите имя (пока) несуществующего файла. в качестве времени укажите ближайшую минуту. или, чтоб не мудрствовать лукаво, укажите звёздочки, но не забудьте потом удалить это задание:

   ```
   * * * * * date >> /tmp/какой-нибудь-файл
   ```

   если спустя несколько секунд после наступления следующей минуты указанный вами файл не был создан, вероятно, в вашей системе всё-таки тем или иным образом запрещено использование *cron* (см. последнее предложение предыдущего пункта) и вам надо обратиться к администратору системы.

   если файл был создан, но пустой, имеет смысл указать полный путь к программе `date` (и в дальнейшем указывать полные пути к программам, в том числи и в скриптах, которые будете запускать с помощью программы *cron*).
4. в более сложных заданиях имеет смысл перенаправлять в файл не только *stdout*, но и *stderr*:

   ```
   какая-нибудь команда >> /tmp/файл 2>&1
   ```

   чтобы в него были записаны и сообщения об ошибках, которые многие программы отправляет как раз в *stderr*.

---

доп. чтение:

- `$ man cron`
- `$ man crontab`
- `$ man 5 crontab`