# Стороннее программное обеспечение не выполняется из cron

Tags: linux, bash, cron

Уважаемое сообщество.

Я попал в тупик и нуждаюсь в чьем-то пинке под спину ибо сам я эту проблему решить не в состоянии.

Идея простая - для того чтобы не засыхала печатающая головка струйного принтера при помощи апликухи принтхелп http://resetters.ru/index.php?showtopic=38584 можно периодически её (головку) чистить. Чтобы не иметь головной боли и не делать это вручную, не беспокоясь о том забыл ты это сделать вчера или нет и не забудешь ли хоть раз в неделю, это можно делать через командную строку.

Я написал скрипт который включил в автозагрузку. Этот скрипт ждет 24 часа (время можно изменить), и выполняет команду:

```
/usr/bin/printhelp --device="Epson L800" --action="cleaning"
```

и все работает как надо. Казалось бы, работает и работает, и радуйся. Но это же костыль. Зачем такое городить? Я же опытный линуксоид. Для таких нужд лучше же использовать cron. Только вот проблема в том, что из-под cron-а эта команда не отрабатывает. Нет на исполнение коммандному процессору она отправляется, но по факту принтер не чистится.

Обращаю Ваше внимание, что путь к апликухе - полный. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть причина и как её лечить? Очень благодарен за все идею.

Comment: 1. пользователь. 2. переменные окружения. 3. [диагностика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/840821/178576). 4. к разработчикам.

Comment: Ищите и читайте логи. Начните с проверки прав

Comment: Возможно, программа хочет иксы, а их под кроном нет.

Comment: **их под кроном нет** - не совсем так. Что бы запустить из под cron-а приложение с GUI, надо в *crontab* написать нечто вроде: *<время запуска> export DISPLAY=:0 && /usr/bin/somedirectory/somecommand*

Answer (score 2):

Позвольте! ПО принтера само паркует головки к памперсу, что бы как раз и не высыхали... У меня лично Canon pixma ip4200 несколько лет пролежал в гараже. После этого сделал только несколько глубоких очисток и калибровку головок - и все! До сих пор пашет...

Comment: Странно, у меня мой этот же L800 несколько месяцев простоял на столе и в результате мне это стояние обошлось в 93$.

Comment: Ну что ж, видимо, Эпсон не считает, что должен заботиться о своих клиентах. А может на это специально расчёт делается, ибо струйники очень дешевы в магазинах, а вот расходники и з/ч, наоборот, дороги....

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо [Roman](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/183980/roman), спасибо [Sergey](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/213498/sergey). Так и оказалось прямо перед дефиницией расписания указал DISPLAY=:0.0 как советовали в [этой](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/cron) статье. Экспортировать переменную оказалось не обязательно хотя можно и экспортировать, работать будет и так и этак. В результате необязательные настройки оказались обязательными ибо хоть printhelp и запускается в консольном режиме, но сама по себе программа иксовая и так или иначе все-равно требует иксы. Узнал я об этом перенаправив вывод команды, вызываемой из cron, в отдельный текстовый файл:

/usr/bin/printhelp --device="Epson L800" --action="cleaning" > /var/log/printerClean.log 2>&1

Естественно в папке с логами файл printerClean.log уже должен существовать иметь определенные права, а также владельца и группу. А логи элементарно было просто лень искать. И, собственно, в файле printerClean.log оказалось сообщений с прямым текстом типа "Володька, сбрей усы и подними иксы". Спасибо Всем кто отозвался и помог, надеюсь этот тред кому-то будет полезен.