# Запуск jar файла с помощью crontab

Tags: linux, debian, jar, crontab

Имеется программа на java, запускаю ее вручную с помощью скрипта start.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar myapp.jar &>myapp.log &
```

все отлично работает.

Хочу чтобы она запускалась автоматически после ребута сервера, делаю запись в crontab -e:

```
@reboot /home/user/myapp-folder/start.sh >> /home/user/myapp-folder/cron.log
```

Однако после перезагрузки программа не стартует, смотрю системные логи:

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

там видно что крон отрабатывает:

```
/var/log/syslog:Sep 16 16:09:35 niksonmobil cron[111]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
/var/log/syslog:Sep 16 16:09:35 niksonmobil cron[111]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
/var/log/syslog:Sep 16 16:09:35 niksonmobil CRON[163]: (root) CMD (/home/user/myapp-folder/start.sh >> /home/user/myapp-folder/cron.log)
```

В моих логах cron.log и cover.log пусто, помогите разобраться.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/840821/178576

Comment: Тестовый скрипт который запускается раз в минуту исправно работает

Comment: Смотрите в /var/mail/user

Comment: А для Вашей myapp.jar Переменных окружения никаких не нужно? А то cron в них не очень умеет. Не получается у Вас та-же ситуация как в [этой](http://onedev.net/post/593) статье?

Comment: а если stderr перенаправить в cron.log тоже ничего?

Comment: В общем не знаю как так получилось, но поставив 10 JDK от Оракл все стало работать без проблем.

Answer (score 0):

Через unit systemd попробуйте:
Создаем в /etc/systemd/system/ файл javascript.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Java Service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/user/myapp-folder/start.sh
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

После того как создали и сохранили:
`sudo systemctl daemon-reload` Перечитать демонов
`sudo systemctl enable javascript` Включить в автозагрузку нашего демона
`sudo systemctl start javascript` Запустить нашего демона

---

> Правда если нужны переменные окружения нужно их будет добавить в раздел `[Service]` как `Environment=VAR_NAME=VAR_VALUE`

Answer (score 0):

укажите полный путь к приложению java в вашем скрипте
посмотреть можно например так:

```
$ whereis java

java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
```