# Проблема запуска .sh в cron

Tags: python, cron, tensorflow, crontab

У меня есть работающий скрипт script.sh:

```
python /opt/facenet/src/train.py
```

Но когда я пытаюсь запустить его в cron, то получаю такую ошибку:

> ImportError: No module named tensorflow

Я пыталась пофиксить это таким способом:

```
import tensorflow
tensorflow.__file__
/home/user/anaconda3/lib/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.pyc
```

Я изменила путь к библиотекам и запустила скрипт вот так:

```
/home/user/anaconda3/lib/site-packages /opt/facenet/src/train.py
```

После чего, получила следующую ошибку:

> /home/user/anaconda3/lib/site-packages: Permission denied

Эту пыталась починить с помощью chmod, однако тоже не помогло.

Мне было предложено запустить скрипт таким образом: ```

```
/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python /opt/facenet/src/train.py
```

Но вновь я получаю ошибку:

> ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Есть идеи, в чем может быть дело?

Comment: `Permission denied`? Попробуйте запустить как `sudo`

Comment: Думаю, что вам правильно посоветовали запускать скрипт с помощью питона из окружения анаконды `/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python /opt/facenet/src/train.py`. Пробуйте решить проблему с `libcublas.so.9.0`. Взгляните на этот вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48428415/importerror-libcublas-so-9-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/840689/178576

Comment: вы используете `VirtualEnv` ?

Comment: @Andrey спасибо, помогло)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я видел похожие проблемы при работе с `VirtualEnv`. В этом случае удобно будет создать небольшой файл, в котором утсанавливаются все переменные окружения, например:

Предположим вы создали Python VirtualEnv и назвали его `ml` (Machine Learning).

Для работы в скриптах можно создать файл окружения (назовем его: $HOME/.ml_env):

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/my/own/python_libs
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/anaconda3/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=$HOME/anaconda3/bin:$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

Потом в SHELL скриптах добавляем след. строки:

```
#!/bin/bash

source $HOME/.ml_env
conda activate ml
```

Comment: Спасибо, ваш ответ помог с решением моей проблемы!

Comment: @arti_lina, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, [проголосуйте за ответ (для этого необходимо иметь как минимум 15 репутационных балов)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) и/или [отметьте его как решение](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) ;-)