# Не выполняется запуск php скрипта по cron

Tags: администрирование, cron, crontab

В файле crontab сделал несколько записей

```
0-59/5 * * * * wget -O - https://мойсайт.ру/мойскрипт > /dev/null
1-59/5 * * * * wget -O - https://мойсайт.ру/мойскрипт1 > /dev/null
3-59/5 * * * * wget -O - https://мойсайт.ру/мойскрипт2 > /dev/null
5-59/5 * * * * wget -O - https://мойсайт.ру/мойскрипт3 > /dev/null
```

Подскажите, может быть есть ошибка?

Когда запускаю через командную строку, то скрипт нормально отрабатывается.

```
wget -O - https://мойсайт.ру/мойскрипт3 > /dev/null
```

ОС CentOS7

Comment: Попробуйте прописать путь полностью `/usr/bin/wget`. Потому, что `$PATH` внутри `cron` не всегда включает путь `/usr/bin`. Если не поможет - смотрите логи и почту рута.

Comment: просто к слову: `0-59/5` отличается от `5-59/5` только в 0 минут (второй вариант не «сработает»). а дальше будет идентично — в 5, 10, 15, 20 и т.д. минут.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/840821/178576