# Почему CRON не выполняет задачу?

Tags: unix, cron

Собственно вот задача, суть которой удалять все фалы в папке myFolder кроме 3 самых новых:

`*/1 * * * * ls -1t /web/backups/myFolder | tail -n +4 | xargs rm -f`

Она успешно выполняется из консоли, а из CRON нет, почему?

Comment: [диагностика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/840821/178576)

Comment: если в скрипте с заданием cron не прописан PATH, то попробуйте прописать абсолютные пути к всем вызываемым программам, либо пропишите `SHELL=/bin/sh` и `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin` в начале файла с заданием