# bash script запускается вручную, однако не запускается если установить его как cron задачу

Tags: linux, bash, cron

У меня есть bash скрипт, который делает запрос на Postgresql и результат после обработки сохраняет(перезаписывая) в файл.

Упрощенно:

```
#!/bin/bash

TEXTDATA="\copy (SELECT json_agg(t) FROM (SELECT itemData FROM items ) as t) to /path/to/my/file.json"

#Мой запрос использующий TEXTDATA

sed -i 's/}, \\n {/}, {/g' /path/to/my/file.json
```

Если я вручную вызываю скрипт в терминале:

```
./myScript.sh
```

То он корректно отрабатывает и сохраняет результат в файл.

Однако если я записываю в crontab(запуская командой `sudo crontab -e`) запись такого вида:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

30 * * * * /bin/bash /home/myName/myScript.sh
```

То скрипт не запускается каждые 30 минут. Пробовал как вместе с SHELL/PATH и /bin/bash, так и без - не работает.

Скажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так и как можно исправить это?

Comment: Права у пользователя и пользователя `cron` разные. Полагаю что `cron` просто не может прочесть ваш файл.

Comment: Как я понимаю, если я меняю `crontab -e` используя команду `sudo`, то оно должно иметь должные права. Пожалуйста поправьте, если не прав

Comment: Права на скрипт были установлены такой командой: `sudo chmod +x ./myScript.sh`

Comment: `sudo` запускает `cron` для пользователя `root`.  Разные пользователи имеют разные `crontab` файлы.

Comment: Если Убунта, то [сюда](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto).

Comment: [диагностика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/840821/178576)

Comment: 0) Почему вы считаете, что с подобной строкой в кронтабе скрипт должен запускаться каждые 30 секунд? (это не так; но мне действительно интересно, почему вы так считаете)

Comment: Помарка: каждые 30 минут, а не 30 секунд. Исправлю текст вопроса

Comment: Ага. Корректирую вопрос: Почему вы считаете, что с подобной строкой в кронтабе скрипт должен запускаться каждые 30 минут? Ну просто интересно, из какого места мануала следует такой вывод?

Comment: Alexander Prokoshev, Начну с того, что во первых даже на SO и SE есть уйма ссылок (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37574962/13912694 || https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/240596 - как примеры). Это же просто выполнение файла в заданное время. Завершу тем, что прямо сейчас у меня на глазах выполняется необходимый мне bash скрипт.

Comment: Простите, но я не понимаю ваше непонимание, ведь как еще его запускать то?

Comment: Ну так по ссылкам же несколько другое написано, согласитесь. То, что у вас, не будет запускаться каждые 30 минут.

Comment: Как вы думаете - я буду обращаться с вопросом на SO, если у меня уже будет работающее решение?)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

В итоге чтобы заработал скрипт мне понадобилось:

1. Выполнить `crontab -e` без `sudo`
2. Убрать `PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin` и `/bin/bash`, но оставить `SHELL=/bin/bash` - без него не работает.
3. Выставить права bash файлу командой `sudo chmod 777 /path/to/myScript.sh`

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

30 * * * * /home/myName/myScript.sh
```

Всем спасибо за помощь.

Comment: можно просто добавить запись напрямую в `/etc/crontab` =)

Comment: crontab -e без sudo запускает от имени пользователя добавившего задачу. с судо от рута