# Cannot add dependency job for unit microcode.service, ignoring: Unit is not loaded properly: Invalid argument

Tags: cron, centos7, crontab

В centos 7, через команду

```
crontab -e
```

вызываю редактор и там добавляю команду

```
* 11 * * * admin1 /usr/bin/sh /data/builds/update.sh
```

Однако в логах выводится сообщение:

```
systemd: Cannot add dependency job for unit microcode.service, ignoring: Unit is not loaded properly: Invalid argument.
```

Как то по другому нужно добавлять команду?

Comment: уберите `admin1`

Comment: Такая же ошибка. Я после редактирования файла вызываю команду ` sudo systemctl start crond.service`

Comment: 1. к приведённой информации сообщение от systemd не имеет никакого отношения. 2. перезапускать crond не надо. 3. ваше задание будет выполняться каждую минуту начиная с 11:00 до 11:59 по часовому поясу, настроенному на вашей машине.

Comment: Вот не выполняется. Логов тоже нет в файле /var/log/messages. А администраторы могут заблокировать таким образом работу с cron?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/840821/178576

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, тут было 2 проблемы.

1. Не были назначены права на исполнение файла.

   chmod +x /data/builds/update.sh
2. В скрипте использовался sudo. Вместо этого сам скрипт нужно запускать от имени root.