# Как поменять звук в терминале Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, crontab

Сначала включаем звук, потом отключаем.
Вводим команду crontab -e для нужной корректировки.

```
MAILTO=""
*/1 * * * * ./1.sh 
#Каждую мунуту включать звук
*/3 * * * * ./2.sh
#Каждые 3 минуты выключать звук
```

Выхожу из редактирования кронтаба Проверяю проходят ли команды

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
Aug  4 11:23:01 PC038002 CRON[19511]: (manager) CMD (./1.sh )
Aug  4 11:24:01 PC038002 CRON[19529]: (manager) CMD (./2.sh )
Aug  4 11:24:01 PC038002 CRON[19530]: (manager) CMD (./1.sh )
```

Но звук не включает и не выключается, в чем может быть проблема?

Скрипт 1.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo START SCRIPT: >> $LOG
echo HI
chmod +x 1.sh
#x-terminal-emulator -e 
pactl set-sink-mute 0 0
```

Скрипт 2.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo START SCRIPT: >> $LOG
echo HI
chmod +x 2.sh
#x-terminal-emulator -e 
pactl set-sink-mute 0 1
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/26068/how-do-you-mute-from-the-command-line

Comment: Не подходит... мне нужно через crontab + скрипты(

Comment: Добавляете в крон соответствующую команду amixer set Master mute

Comment: Можно всё это сделать без использования amixer? Только через два скрипта (1.sh и 2.sh (Включение и выключение звука соответственно) )
А в кроне прописывать, что включать звук каждый день в 8ч и выключать в 16 50

Comment: вроде бы абсолютно очевидно, что проблема кроется внутри загадочного скрипта `1.sh`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin 
#!/bin/sh
#PATH=/home/Документы/'Включение звука'
echo START SCRIPT: >> $LOG
#x-terminal-emulator
#cd Документы/'Включение звука'
x-terminal-emulator -e pactl set-sink-mute 0 0

Comment: 1. а зачем вы пытаетесь запустить `x-terminal-emulator`? 2. форматированный текст лучше вставлять в текст вопроса - комментарии для этого совсем не подходят.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin подправил, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/840821/178576

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin По диагностике всё норм

Comment: что, никаких сообщений об ошибках ваши скрипты не выводят? верится с трудом.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin сделал вывод ошибок, вот что пишет 
```/bin/sh: 1: ./1.sh: not found```

Comment: попробуйте сопоставить местонахождение ваших скриптов (к которым вы обращаетесь по относительному, а не абсолютному пути) с тем каталогом, который является текущим при выполнении cron-заданий (воспользовавшись встроенной в оболочку командой pwd).

Answer (score -1):

Добавьте в скрипт переменные окружения со своими путями

```
XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
DISPLAY=:0
```

и может быть что-то ещё, чтоб в кроне было вижно Вашу сессию. Запустите команду через dbus-launch - помогает правильно связаться с dbus-управляекмыми сервисами.

```
dbus-launch pactl set-sink-mute 0 1
```

Comment: ```./1.sh: 10: ./1.sh: dbus-lauch: not found``` вот что выводит

Comment: @Nik вы опечатались

Comment: подправил, без кронтаба скрипты работают, через кронтаб - нет 

```Aug  4 13:32:01 PC038002 CRON[22128]: (manager) CMD (./1.sh )```

```Aug  4 13:33:01 PC038002 CRON[22135]: (manager) CMD (./1.sh )```

```Aug  4 13:33:01 PC038002 CRON[22137]: (manager) CMD (./2.sh )```

Comment: XAUTHORITY и DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS правильно выставил?

Comment: это у меня такие, у Вас также?

Comment: если я все правильно понял и посмотреть можно через ```ls -l```
, то да, такие же..

Comment: @Nik, список (и присвоенные им значения) переменных окружения можно увидеть с помощью программы `env`.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin спасибо.!

Comment: @eri Да, такие же

Comment: ```DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus```
```XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000```
```XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority```