# cron - задание на срабатывает

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

Хочу сделать периодический бэкап базы.

Сначала я написал скрипт, который всё делает. Сделал, чтобы он не зависел от переменных окружения - прочитал заранее про трудноссти с кроном.

Дописал в `/etc/crontab` строчку

```
    00 23 * * 1-5 root /mssql_data/Backups/backup.sh
```

... и на следующе утро увидел, что скрипт не сработал и в логах, котрые я вижу по команде `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` нет записей, относящихся к дописанной строчке.

Понял, что cron я готовить не умею :-)

Исправил команду на ту, проще которой придумть не смог:

```
    30 11 * * 1-5 root cp /mssql_data/Backups/test.sh /mssql_data/Backups/test1.sh
```

Она - как видите - должна сскопировать существующий файл test.sh в другой файл.

Команда также не выполняется.

Проверил - командой `ps -A | grep cron` - что cron в списке процессов есть.

При этом в логах `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` я вижу записи о выполнеи по крону другмих команд, например:

```
    Oct 28 07:17:01 LB3 CRON[312501]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
    Oct 28 08:17:01 LB3 CRON[313928]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Может, этот cron надо как то перезапускть, или как то еще "говорить" ему, что я в файл дописал для него новую команду? Или еще какая то причина, что мой скрипт не работает?

Спасибо за советы!

**Дополнение**

Уважаемые AlexeyTen и ipatev_nn, спасибо большео за Ваши советы!

я даже не ожидал, что мне будет оказана такая помощь в решении проблемы.

Пока проблема еще не решена, несмотря на советы, хотя  я придумал ловкий костыль: каждый час запускать задание, в которм смотреть "а не наступил ли нужный час?" и если наступил - делать бэкап :-)

Теперь о том, что на сервере:

вывод команды `timedatectl`:

```
                       Local time: Thu 2021-10-28 17:22:33 MSK
                   Universal time: Thu 2021-10-28 14:22:33 UTC
                         RTC time: Thu 2021-10-28 14:22:33
                        Time zone: Europe/Moscow (MSK, +0300)
        System clock synchronized: yes
                      NTP service: active
                  RTC in local TZ: no
```

вывод команды `grep "TZ" /etc/cron.d/* /etc/crontab` - пустой

Попытка получить `$TZ` из переменных окружения крона - показывает, что такой переменной нет или она пустая (то есть, файл создаётся, туда пишется пустота)

Вообще, я сделал `printenv` от имени крона и увидел, что переменных там кот наплакал:

```
        HOME=/root
        LOGNAME=root
        PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
        LANG=en_US.UTF-8
        SHELL=/bin/sh
        PWD=/root
```

вывод команды `sudo hwclock -D`: (без sudo работать не хотела)

```
        hwclock: use --verbose, --debug has been deprecated.
        2021-10-28 17:37:22.885307+03:00
```

Самое смешное - я *уверен* что перезагрузка сервака решила бы проблему. Но перезагружать его крайне нежелательно...

**Дополнение 2**

Напомню, с чего всё началось: я подключился к серваку, обнаружил, что часы идут по UTC. Настроил таймзону. Перезапустил крон и сислог. получил в них вроде бы правильное время. Но... задания в кроне, поставленные на определенный час и минуту - не срабатывали.

Вообще, идея ipatev_nn поставить задание по часам в UTC - была крутая. Я "завел будильник" на 15:00, и в 18:00 задание выполнилось и... вывело в файл, что сейчас 18:00 (что, конечно же, правда). Даже sudo `hwclock --debug` не понадобился.

В общем, гитика такая: завожу будильник на три часа раньше, до тех пор, пока сервер не перезагрузится в силу естественных причин :-) потом можно будет заводить  по человечески.

А разгадка, похоже, крылась в том, что команда `sudo hwclock --verbose` пишет вот что:

```
    hwclock from util-linux 2.34
    System Time: 1635439601.588493
    Trying to open: /dev/rtc0
    Using the rtc interface to the clock.
    Assuming hardware clock is kept in UTC time.
    Waiting for clock tick...
    ...got clock tick
    Time read from Hardware Clock: 2021/10/28 16:46:42
    Hw clock time : 2021/10/28 16:46:42 = 1635439602 seconds since 1969
    Time since last adjustment is 1635439602 seconds
    Calculated Hardware Clock drift is 0.000000 seconds
    2021-10-28 19:46:41.577108+03:00
```

И еще раз, на картинке, где подчеркнуто время, на которое, веротяно, и "смотрит" cron:

[image: разница во времени]

Comment: Проще пять звёздочек поставить. И лучше не править `crontab`, а завести новый файл в `/etc/cron.d`

Comment: @AlexeyTen - спасибо за ценную подсказку, начал делать так, добился такого результата: задание "с пятью звездочками" работает (прямо как коньяк) стабильно и раз в минуту. Как только меняю звездочки на минуты и часы - не работает :-( На что еще можно посмотреть?

Comment: А дата и время на ПК заведены правильно? Крон сам подгружает задания, конечно можно сделать `reload`, но если задания со звездочками заработало корректно, то возможно проблема со временем

Comment: @ipatev_nn - спасибо за подсказку, такая мысль пришла мне в голову, и я действительно устанавливал время на сервере на локальное (было UTC). Потом я перезапустил и крон, и syslog (чтобы в логах тоже стало правильное локальное время). Сейчас результат такой: я могу запустить скрипт каждый час (30 * * * * root tst.sh). На запук в определенное время, когда указаны и часы и минуты - не реагирует :-) Это заставляет меня думать, что где то в системе время всё таки осталось неправильным. Написал скрипт, котороый должен выполниться в полночь и записать в файл время, в которое он выполнился. пробую...

Comment: А зачем ждать полуночи? Можно же и в ежеминутном сделать вывод date

Comment: @AlexeyTen - в ежеминутном режиме - выводится правильная дата - время. То есть, команда dt=$(date '+%Y.%m.%d_%H-%M');
echo $dt > tm.txt только что вывела мне правильное значение '2021.10.28_14-37'. но стОит мне добавить в команду не только минуты, но и часы - что то идёт не так...

Comment: Я бы просто сделал 24 строчки с разными часами и разным выводом и посмотрел какая сработает =)

Comment: @AlexeyTen - спасибо, да, это хороший совет, он мне тоже приходил в голову :-) я постараюсь написать продолжение, когда разберусь, в чем же было дело

Comment: Сам крон перезапускать пробовали?

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev - да, сам крон - перезапускал. как я понимаю, сейчас мой вопрос свелся к тому, что hwclock показывает время, отстающее на три часа от установленного в системе. Почему - непонятно :-) Я попробовал всю магию, котрую рекомендует хелп по hwclock - ничего не привело к тоу, что эти два времени, показанные на картинке, совпали

Comment: Странно всё это. Дело в том, что ситуация, когда железные часы идут по UTC - абсолютно штатная, у меня нет машин, где было бы по-другому. Крону настройки HW clock до лампочки (как и всем остальным программам, кроме hwclock).

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev - Спасибо, я тоже слазил на домашний сервер и посмотрел на нём hwclock - там тоже железные часы идут по UTC. Ну ничего, костыль (стаить все задания на 3 часа  раньше - тогда они выполнятся вовремя) есть, теперь проживём!

Comment: @S.H. аппаратные часы попробуйте настроить так `hwclock --systohc --utc`

Comment: @ipatev_nn - спасибо за участие. команду выполнил, но на работу крон - заданий она не повлияла - по прежнему завожу будильник на три часа раньше :-) - уже привык

Comment: [диагностика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/840821/178576)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас все же складывается впечатление, что проблемы со временем все же присутствуют на сервере, а если основываться на комментарии:

> Сейчас результат такой: я могу запустить скрипт каждый час (30 * * * * root tst.sh).

То вероятнее всего именно с часовыми поясами.

Рекомендую проверить:

1. `timedatectl` - корректность настроенного времени и часового пояса
2. `grep "TZ" /etc/cron.d/* /etc/crontab` - возможно часовой пояс установлен для самого задания cron
3. `* * * * * root echo "$TZ" > /tmp/croncheck.tmp` - так как данную переменную cron может брать из окружения, добавить задание и проверить, что записывается пустота или корректная временная зона
4. `hwclock -D` - проверка аппаратного времени, выведет время и часовой пояс в системе.

---

В случае если это не поможет в исправлении проблемы, то приложите вывод команд из пункта 1 и 4 к вопросу

Comment: Спасибо! я дописал вывод команд в вопрос...

Comment: @S.H. а попробуйте поставить задание, только в UTC, т.е. -3 часа от МСК и `sudo hwclock --debug`, так как ключ `-D` в вашей версии не сработал

Comment: все, разобрался, дополнил информацией сам вопрос! Вопрос о том, как "скорректировать" время в hwclock - интересный, но пока не знаю...

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте тот же лог `/var/log/syslog`.

Например я сделал ошибку и вот что там пишут:

```
$ fgrep cron /var/log/syslog
[...]
Oct 28 13:31:01 hera cron[1096]: Error: bad minute; while reading /etc/cron.d/cron-check
Oct 28 13:31:01 hera cron[1096]: (*system*cron-check) ERROR (Syntax error, this crontab file will be ignored)
```

Comment: Спасибо, да, я всё время в этот файл поглядываю, но пока просто вижу, что скрипт с указанием минут для запуска (30 * * * * root tst.sh) - работает, а если я добавляю часы и минуты (30 13 * * * root tst.sh) - не работает. Продолжаю пробовать...