# cPanel не работает cron

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

Создад в cPanel крона. Он должен вызывать каждые 2 минуты скрипт `cron.php`, который пока что просто записывает в файл `log.txt` текущее время и дублирует это в `print`.

Когда я открываю скрипт вручную, всё срабатывает, а вот крон, сколько б я не ждал, скрипт не выполнил.

Код `cron.php`:

```
<?php
print(date("D M d, Y G:i"));
file_put_contents("log.txt", date("D M d, Y G:i")."\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
```

Вот, что я вижу в панели уравления:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [шаги диагностики](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/840821/178576)

Comment: я понятия не имею куда вписывать эти команды, тут можно только относительный путь скрипта дописать

Comment: В кроне надо указывать часы и минуты срабатывания, а не интервал. То есть, указать в часах *, а в минутах - все минуты в часе, при которых он должен запускаться: 0,2,4,6 и тд

Comment: я понимаю, но тут это делается через интерфейс, саму команду вводить нельзя