# cron+browser+log

Tags: linux, bash, get, cron, sudo

Требуется настроить cron, чтобы он каждую минуту или час запрашивал сайт и выводил содержимое в файл.
Пробовал и так

```
* * * * * wget 'http://example.stag/script/newfid'>/home/dev/Desktop/cron.log
```

И даже так

```
* * * * * curl --request GET http://example.stag/script/newfid'>/home/dev/Desktop/cron.log
```

Файл пустой, может что-то запрашивается, но отчёт требуется. Чтобы точно быть уверенным в том, что запрос прошёл, а сайт своё дело сделал.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/840821/178576

Comment: Проверял, работает. Но не отрабатывает. Есть по соседству команда * * * * *   echo 'test"  >/home/dev/Desktop/cron2.log
Она срабатывает. эта работает а та где надо гет запрос сделать нет

Comment: т.е., программа crond работает. ну, значит, разбирайтесь с вашей командой. начните с её запуска.

Comment: В консоле отрабатывает, что та что другая. Но именно через крон она не работает, и не логирует свои действия

Comment: Пробелы  важны возле `>`.

Comment: Может к wget/curl указать полный путь, где они? Из `which -a wget`.

Comment: Скрипт сам по себе, крон работает, не работает вывод

Comment: И ещё, вы сколько ждёте отработки скрипта, когда запускаете его вручную?

Comment: Загляните в системный лог, или лог самого cron. Возможно там будет ответ на вашу проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Желательно использовать полный путь к командам **curl/wget**, как рекомендовали в комментариях.

Адрес сайта лучше взять в кавычки. Вместо одного > нужно использовать >> - иначе раз в минуту лог будет перезаписываться.(если требуется ежеминутный лог)

--request GET - обычно это можно опустить.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/curl "http://example.stag/script/newfid" >> /home/dev/Desktop/cron.log
```

В случае каких либо ошибок, в почтовом ящике пользователя - если выполняется от рута, то обычно это: **/var/spool/mail/root** - должен быть отчёт об ошибке.