# Не выполняется Python скрипт main.py на удаленном хостинге через cron

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, cron

Пытаюсь запустить скрипт main.py на удаленном хостинге. Виртуальное окружение создал, права под рута папке тоже:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1354 окт 26 08:55 database.py  
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6136 окт 26 08:55 get_data.py  
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3640 окт 26 08:55 main.py  
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 окт 26 09:05 __pycache__  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 окт 26 09:10 python3  
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  333 окт 26 08:56 settings.py  
drwxrwxrwx 6 root root 4096 окт 26 08:36 venv
```

Из терминала вручную скрипт запускается по команде:
source /home/geoserver/ff/venv/bin/activate ; python3 main.py
и работает правильно.

Но мне нужно выполнять скрипт по расписанию. Поэтому создал строку запуска скрипта в cron при запуске ежеминутно:

```
*/1 * * * * root source /home/geoserver/ff/venv/bin/activate ; python3 main.py
```

cron запускается каждую минуту и выдает логи как этот:

```
CRON[4033]: (root) CMD (source /home/geoserver/ff/venv/bin/activate ; python3 main.py)
```

Однако по факту скрипт не запускается, данные в базу не прилетают. В чем может быть проблема, как узнать есть ли ошибки у cron и какие они?

Comment: Смотрите в логах системы. Где лог именно крона может зависеть от того, какой именно у вас линукс.

Comment: Пробуйте указать полный путь к скрипту

Comment: Попробуйте прописать PATH=/usr/bin/python3 если еще не прописан.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/840821/178576

Comment: ну и внутренняя команда интерпретатора `source` в данном случае, скорее всего, работать не будет. потому что и не должна. лучше явно вызвать интерпретатор. bash, например: `bash -c 'source чего-то-там; команда; ещё команда'`. ах, да, про смену каталога не забудьте. туда, где этот ваш `main.py` находится

Comment: @CrazyElf, вывод задания по умолчанию отправляется владельцу задания по почте. так что не логи, а mail spool (не знаю, как правильно термин звучит по-русски) надо советовать смотреть.

Comment: если передача почты во внешний мир на сервере не настроена, то можно хоть глазами посмотреть содержимое: `$ less /var/spool/пользователь`, хоть программой mail (в некоторых особо извращённых дистрибутивах может отсутствовать по умолчанию).

Comment: "лучше явно вызвать интерпретатор. bash" @aleksandr-barakin это решило проблему!! Касаемо пути к python3, то я пробовал и явно указывать ссылку на python из проекта, и изменять корневую директорию.  Большое спасибо!!!

Comment: Итоговое решение: */1 * * * * bash -c 'cd /home/geoserver/ff/; source /home/geoserver/ff/venv/bin/activate ; python3 main.py'   Осталось вывод ошибок на почту прикрутить.

Comment: @Smopuim_81 если переход в директорию сделали, то и activate можно по относительному пути делать.

Comment: `Осталось вывод ошибок на почту прикрутить` — по умолчанию вывод cron-заданий и так отправляется «на почту» (в «mail spool», если точнее). а вот чтобы эта почта уходила за пределы данной машины, вам какой-нибудь smtp-клиент надо установить и настроить. ну, хотя бы msmtp или что-то аналогично-минимальное, чтобы не морочить голову с монстрами типа exim/postfix/и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Надо так

```
*/1 * * * * root /home/geoserver/ff/venv/bin/python3 main.py
```

Питоны, если не изменяет мне память  новее 3.5 , отлично подхватывают своё окружение.