# Certbot на сервере Linux не работает авто-обновление SSL сертификатов LetsEncript

Tags: certbot

В крон добавлена команда
59 * * * * certbot renew --post-hook "/usr/sbin/nginx -s reload" >> /var/log/certbot_renew.log
То есть, запуск certbot renew каждые 59 минут.
При этом когда остается 30 дней до окончания действия SSL сертификатов LetsEncript, автообовление не происходит.
Когда выполняю руками из консоли sudo certbot renew, все отлично обновляется.
В конфиге раскомментирована директива:
renew_before_expiry = 30 days
Данные сервера
nginx/1.20.2
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)

Comment: [для начала](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/840821/178576)